# Is it a must to apply Australian tourist visa from the country you are departing from?

Tags: visas, international-travel, australia

I am an Indonesian citizen living in Shenzhen on a student visa. I am planning to travel to Australia from Shenzhen next year. **I was wondering if I can apply for an Australian short-visit visa in Indonesia even though I will be departing from Shenzhen?** It does not specify anything regarding this in the [official website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder/visit) or any other websites for that matter... but when I asked my travel agent in Indonesia, he says that I must apply for an Australian visa in Shenzhen... I am not sure if he is right. Has anyone experienced the same? Or can anyone help confirm this information?

Comment: This does not sound correct but might depend on VISA type, I am a Swedish passport holder and applied on the WEB from Thailand and departed from China.

Comment: When does your student visa expire? Are you planning on returning to Shenzhen after your trip to Australia?

Comment: @Traveller My student visa expires in September next year and I am planning to visit Australia in March. Yes, I will be returning to Shenzhen after my trip.

Comment: You don’t need to use a travel agent AFAIK. According to https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/contact-us/offices-and-locations/offices-outside-australia you can apply online and give biometrics at one of the Australian Visa Application Centres in Beijing, Guangzhou, and Shanghai.

Comment: @Traveller Yes, I am aware. However, I plan to depart from Shenzhen shortly after I arrive in the city. I am not sure less than one month is enough for me to travel back and forth to Guangzhou (the closest from Shenzhen) for the visa application... so I was thinking of applying for one in Indonesia beforehand. Not sure if that works... :/

Comment: @Tina Sorry, I meant to comment that there does not appear to be a stipulation regarding applying for a short term visa from one’s home / country of residence. I selected China by mistake

Comment: If there is a limitation it is very unlikely to be "country you are departing from". That sort of requirement would make multi-country tours impossible. Some countries do require application in your country of residence.

Comment: @MattDouhan May I know how much time did it take for you to get your visa?

Comment: @Tina about 5 minutes

Comment: As a general rule it is best to avoid taking visa advice or obtaining visa services from travel agents. Too many of them are unscrupulous and will intentionally sabotage people's applications (and some don't know what they are doing and will accidentally sabotage people's applications). You're almost always better off to apply for the visa yourself.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think you’re right. I knew it from the moment he gave me that half-hearted information. I’ve never used a travel agent for my visas before so I guess I’m gonna keep it that way... :/

Comment: @Tina you can apply for an Australian visa online, anywhere.